# Type X is not assignable to type Y

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have this category interface

```
export interface ISubCategory {
    _id: string,
    name: string,
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
}
export interface ICategory {
    _id: string,
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date,
    name: string,
    subCategories: ISubCategory[],
    _v? : string | number
}

export interface ICategories{
    categories : ICategory[]
}
```

On my home page, I called the API to get categories

```
const fetchCategories = async () => {
    const data : ICategories = await getCategories()
    setCategories(data)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories()
  }, [])
```

and the getCategories is here

```
export async function getCategories (){
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/categories')
    const data = response.data.data
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return error
  }
}
```

And when I passed these categories to child component an error occur.
Type 'ICategories | []' is not assignable to type 'ICategory[]'.
Type 'ICategories' is missing the following properties from type 'ICategory[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
here is how I am passing categories to child component and receiving it in child component

```
  return (
    <Div>
      <DropDownContextProvider>
        <Header categories={categories} />

         <Slider />
      </DropDownContextProvider>
    </Div>
  )
```

and here how I am receiving it

```
const Header = ({ categories }: ICategories ) => {
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The categories are of type array and changed my interface to this

```
export interface ISubCategory {
    _id: string,
    name: string,
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
   }
export interface ICategory {
    _id: string,
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date,
    name: string,
    subCategories: ISubCategory[] | [],
    _v? : string | number
}
```

and removed ICategories interface and the categories state set as ICategory[] | []

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState<ICategory[] | []>([])
  const fetchCategories = async () => {
    const data = await getCategories()
    setCategories(data)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories()
  }, [])
```

and then received props in header component as this

```
const Header = ({ categories }: { categories:ICategory[] | [] }) => {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the return response, you need to build the object to support the  `ICategories` interface

```
export async function getCategories (){
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/categories')
    const data = response.data.data
    return {categories: data}
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return {categories: []}

  }
}
```